# Swift thread safe array

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create thread-safe array for piping data between threads

```
public class SyncArray<T> {
  
  public var dataArray = [T]()
  private var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
  
  public init() {
    
  }
  
  private func wait() { semaphore.wait() }
  private func signal() { semaphore.signal() }
  
  public func count() -> Int {
    var count = 0;
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    count = dataArray.count
    return count;
  }
  
  public func unshift() -> T? {
    var firstEl:T? = nil
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    if(self.count() > 0){
      firstEl = dataArray.removeFirst()
    }
    return firstEl;
  }
  
  public func pop() -> T? {
    var lastEl:T? = nil
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    if(self.count() > 0){
      lastEl = dataArray.popLast()
    }
    return lastEl;
  }
  
  public func append(value: T) -> Void {
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    dataArray.append(value)
  }
}
```

Pipe data

```
   
    let buff = SyncArray<Container>()
   
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      do {
        let dataSource = getDataSource()
        for i in 0 ..< dataSource.length{
          buff.append(value: dataSource[i])
        }
    }
```

```
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      while(true) {
        let data = buff.unshift()
      }
    }
```

The idea is to pipe data between threads. For some reason `buff.append` and `buff.unshift` deadlocks eachother

i tried allso

```
 public func count() -> Int {
    wait();
    count = dataArray.count
    signal()
    return count;
  }
```

Same result. Please, advise what am I doing wrong. I feel the fix should be super simple. Thanks!

Comment: I'd put a wrapper around NSLock

Comment: @Rob do you know how to correctly wrap shared resources in NSLock? my previous version was through three NSLocks but i got SIGSEGV error because ```append``` and ```pop``` used different locks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `unshift` calls `count`.  `unshift` is already holding the semaphore, but the first thing that `count` does is call `wait`, which causes a deadlock. You have the same problem in `popLast`.

Since you already have exclusive access to the array you can simply use its `isEmpty` property.

```
public func unshift() -> T? {
    var firstEl:T? = nil
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    if !dataArray.isEmpty {
      firstEl = dataArray.removeFirst()
    }
    return firstEl;
  }

public func pop() -> T? {
    var lastEl:T? = nil
    wait(); defer { signal() }
    if !dataArray.isEmpty {
      lastEl = dataArray.popLast()
    }
    return lastEl;
  }
```

You could also replace your `DispatchSemaphore` with a [`NSRecursiveLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrecursivelock) since you don't need the counting behaviour of a semaphore. `NSRecursiveLock` can be `lock`ed multiple times by the same thread without causing a deadlock.